# Create multistep form without angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

[please look image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1vLZ.png)I need to create a multi step form without using Angular UI Router & angular material.
could any one help me.

```
<div class="wizard">
  <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/customer-dashboard/customer-information/information-form']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      Submit Information
  </a>
  <a [class.disabled]="idTab" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/customer-dashboard/customer-information/id-form']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
      Submit Id
  </a>
  <a  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/customer-dashboard/customer-information/verify-identity']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
      Verify Identity
  </a>
  <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/customer-dashboard/customer-information/final-validation']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
    Final Validation
  </a>
  <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/customer-dashboard/customer-information/approval']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
    Approval
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? :-)

Comment: Why not simply create a large Form, create a variable "step" and use *ngIf="step==0", *ngIf="step==1"... to show the steps? Tip: before increment step, check is is valid each control in the step

Comment: You don't need the router, there's already example from Angular Material: https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnaarnjeodr?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts

Comment: In my application, angular material is not used. I want to do it in custom way.

Answer (score 1):

working [CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-vxcg0?fontsize=14)

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <span class="state-container" [ngStyle]="state === 1 && {'color': 'red'}"
    >state 1</span
  >
  <span class="state-container" [ngStyle]="state === 2 && {'color': 'red'}"
    >state 2</span
  >
  <span class="state-container" [ngStyle]="state === 3 && {'color': 'red'}"
    >state 3</span
  >
</div>
<div *ngIf="state === 1">
  <form #f1="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)" novalidate>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" />
    <label for="family">Family</label>
    <input name="family" id="family" [(ngModel)]="user.family" />
    <button (click)="next(user)">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="state === 2">
  <form #f2="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)" novalidate>
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input name="address" id="family" [(ngModel)]="user.address" />
    <button (click)="back()">Back</button>
    <button (click)="next(user)">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="state === 3">
  <p>The End</p>

  <button (click)="back()">Back</button>
  <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
  <button (click)="save(user)">Save</button>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
interface User {
  name: string;
  family: string;
  address: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  state = 1;
  user: User;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = {
      name: "",
      family: "",
      address: ""
    };
  }
  save(user: User) {
    alert("Final Result:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(user));
  }
  next(user: User) {
    ++this.state;
    alert(JSON.stringify(user));
  }
  back() {
    --this.state;
  }
  reset() {
    this.state = 1;
    this.user = {
      name: "",
      family: "",
      address: ""
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I personally don't recommend this approach. Just remember, If you don't save the data and refresh the page your data is gone.

Comment: how to make step1, step2 & step3 also clickable to load particular form on click?

Comment: I updated the previous [codesanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-vxcg0?fontsize=14) . All you need to do is to add ``(click)=" state = 1 " `` to every state label in order to change the state. I recommend to have some validation for each form and make user to fill them out.

Comment: Thanks @sima Amini, I am able to done my job that is required. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MukeshKumar You're welcome! If my answer was useful, please mark it as an answer. Thanks.